# How to import custom qml components via import <Module>.<Submodule> statements?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

Here is my directory structure

```
Myproject
 |- KmcUI
     |- Controls
          |- MyComponent1.qml
          |- qmldir
          |- impl
              |- InternalComponent.qml
              |- qmldir
     |- Window
          |- MyComponent2.qml
          |- qmldir
     |- MyComponent3.qml
     |- qmldir
 |- main.qml
```

I have following quesitons:

1. Should I write 3 `qmldir` files in `./KmcUI`, `./KmcUI/Controls` and `./KmcUI/Window`, respectively? If so, how to write them?
2. How to install import path? I've tried add `absolute/path/to/Propject/KmcUI` to `QML_IMPORT_PATH` environment variable/`.pro` file and `QQmlEngine::addImportPath()`, but none of them worked.

**EDIT**
According to comments, I wrote `qmldir` for each submodule, and the updated directory is shown above. And the content of each `qmldir`, for example, in `.\KmcUI\Window\qml`:

```
module KmcUI.Window
MyComponent2 1.0 MyComponent2.qml
```

But still doesn't work. Besides, if I want to use `InternalComponent`, I cannot even use `import KmcUI.Controls.impl` in `MyComponent1.qml`.

Comment: The Qt documents are pretty clear - [Importing QML Document Directories](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-syntax-directoryimports.html#directory-listing-qmldir-files), [Import Statements](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-syntax-imports.html). Did you follow that?

Comment: @folibis Yes, I have read it for many times, but I still cannot make it work.

Comment: please clarify what you have already done and what exactly didn't work

Comment: @folibis I've mentioned what I have done in question. Do you mean you want to check my `qmldir`?

Comment: 1. AFAIK, the naming doesn't follow a cascading rule. You only need to declare one `qmldir` files for every submodule, but you can use a dot (`.`) in the naming to make it more readable.
2. If the `.qml` files are placed inside resources, add the `qrc` path to the engine using `importPath`. Additionally, note that `QML_IMPORT_PATH` is only used by the IDE to detect the modules.

Comment: @SMR 1. However, AFAIK, a module declaration must be located at the first line of `qmldir`. How to declare `KmcUI`, `KmcUI.Controls`, `KmcUI.Window` and `KmcUI.Window.impl` at the same time? 2. Did you mean that I must add all of the `.qml` file in `./KmcUI` and its subdirectory to `qrc` file? Is there a more convenient way to do, like include a `.pri` or a separate `.qrc` file?

Comment: @Kamichanw Sorry, I mean every module should be declared in separate files. One for `KmcUI.Controls` and another for `KmcUI.Window`. And if I'm not mistaken, you should have presented your files with your project, either beside your release files or as a resource inside the executable file. So, you should add the path to your `qmldir` file to your import path, which should also be in a directory with the same name as your modules. If you separated your modules using a period (`.`), the directory should also be like this: `KmcUI/Controls/qmldir`.

Comment: @SMR I have updated my directory structure. Could you please tell me how to install these modules correctly? How to use `import KmcUI.Controls.impl` in KmcUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution!!! Everyone who is confused by Qt documentation should read my answer.

You should do the following:

1. Write `qmldir` for every sub directory, just like I described in question.
2. Add all of the `qmldir`s and `.qml` files to a `.qrc` file that located in the outermost directory, in my case, is `.\KmcUi`. Don't forget to **change the default prefix  `\` to the module name**, in my case, is `KmcUI`.
3. Create a `.pri` file, just include the `.qrc` just created in step 3. This step is optional, the most important is ensuring add `.qrc` in your `.pro`.
4. In your own `.pro` file, include `.pri` or `.qrc` created in step 3 or step 2.
5. Call `engine.addImportPath("qrc:/")`. You can also add following line to your `.pro` file. Then use `INSTALL_PATH(engine)`.

```
DEFINES += INSTALL_PATH\\(E\\)=\"E.addImportPath(QStringLiteral(\\\"qrc:/\\\"));\"
```

6. Import your module in your own qml file!